# Execute command with LXC on remote host

Tags: linux, lxc

I know I can use `lxc exec remote:container -- command` to execute commands on containers living on remote servers.

But, is it possible to execute a command on the remote **host** instead: `lxc exec remote -- command` ?

I need this because I need to run a command on the remote hosts, but I don't won't to start a new SSH connection to each of them, but rather do it from the main server.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question.. it is not possible. You can either connect to the other server or SSH to it from the first one.